# gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found after update

Tags: gnupg

I recently upgraded my base system and now gpg with version 2.1.x is in use. Unfortunately it does not read my old keyrings any more.
As I see from [here](https://www.gnupg.org/faq/whats-new-in-2.1.html) the gpg system should convert it automatically, however this is not happening in my Ubuntu. How can the old format converted then manually?

Answer (score 0):

Somehow there was a migration happening in the past already, so there existed following file already: .gpg-v21-migrated. But the new gpg version could not read or find any migrated files. So I removed the file and the keyrings got reimported:

> rm ~/.gnupg/.gpg-v21-migrated

Comment: I did that, got a "migration succeeded", but still the same errors...